# Counterexample for the monotonicity of Lebesgue dimension?

Tags: general-topology

I recall reading that the Lebesgue dimension isn't monotone, ie. that one can find spaces $V,W: V \subset W, \dim W<\dim V$. But I wasn't able to find any such examples on my own, nor could I find any article or book that would provide any not hidden behind a paywall. Reading Engelking's dimension theory, I've found a theorem on compactification:

For every separable metric space $X$ there exists a compactification $\tilde{X}$ such that $\dim{\tilde X} \leq \dim X$

So I guess one just needs to find an example where the inequality is strict.

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/341533/dimension-of-subspace-is-greater-then-dimension-of-space)