# Covering dimensions of a locally compact Hausdorff space and its compactifications

Tags: general-topology, dimension-theory-analysis

Let $X$ be a topological space. Its Lebesgue dimension / topological covering dimension $dim(X)$ is defined as the minimal number $n$ for which, for every open cover $\{U\}$ of $X$ there is an open cover $\{V\}$ that refines $\{U\}$ such that every point $x\in X$ is contained in no more than $n+1$ sets of $\{V\}$. If no such minimal $n$ exists, $X$ is said to have infinite covering dimension.

Now, **let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space that is *not* compact**, $X^\star$ be its one-point compactification, and $\beta X$ be its Stone-Cech compactification. It is direct to see that when $X=\mathbb{R}^n$, $dim(X)=dim(X^\star)$.

**Question:** Can one comment on $dim(X)$, $dim(X^\star)$, and $dim(\beta X)$ in the general case (as in, is there any ordering between them in general?)

I think there is another [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/341533) and an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/341595) that deals with somewhat related issues (for normal spaces), but that does not answer this question directly, I think.

$X$ is *not* a closed subspace of $X^\star$ or of $\beta X$, as it is not compact, so most of the usual theorems about closed subspaces having lower covering dimension, do not apply here (I think).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any $T_4$ space $X$ $\dim(X)=\dim(\beta X)$ (e.g. see Engelking's dimension theory book, chapter 4; but I believe it's also in his "general topology" book), and it's clear also that $\dim(X^\ast)=\dim(X)$ for all locally compact Hausdorff spaces (addition theorems will show this e.g.)

Engelking later in chapter 4 shows also that a $T_4$ space has a compactfication of the same covering dimension such that the compactification has the same weight as well (which $\beta(X)$ will not have, in general).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer... I am presently going through Engelking's text on dimension theory, and I believe I shall be able to find there a proof of what you stated. It seems, though, it is chapter 3 of this text, rather than chapter 4, which is relevant (both the 1978 book "Dimension Theory" and the 1995 book "Theory of Dimensions Finite and Infinite"): it is chapter 3 that deals with the covering dimension, with the last section of the same dedicated to compactifications, while chapter 4 deals with metrizable spaces...

Comment: @UjanChakraborty I think you’re right. I was looking at the modern book, the chapter on covering dimension.  It’s quite technical but quite clear, especially if you know his general topology book.